# Method threw 'javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException' exception. Cannot evaluate domain.MerchantTag$HibernateProxy$zHiEXWeN.toString()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

friends. I have a some problem. I hope you can help me. I have merchant table, model, repository and service.

**Merchant.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Merchant")
public class Merchant {

    @Id
    private String term;
    private String tag;
    @Column(name = "tag_full")
    private String tagFull;
}
```

**MerchantRepository.java**

```
public interface MerchantRepository extends JpaRepository<Merchant, String> {
}
```

**MerchantService.java**

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MerchantService {

    private final MerchantRepository merchantRepository;

    public Merchant getOne(String term) {
        return merchantRepository.getOne(term);
    }
}
```

The getOne function works correctly if I send a value that is in the table. But if I send a value that is not in the table, I get an error. How can i resolve this problem?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should Use findeOne() Instead getOne().
We use getOne() when The Entity is available.
findOne() return Optional,Should Check If It Was Present , use get() to return Entity.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use findeOne() Instead getOne(). I think it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

invoking `getOne()` may return a lazily fetched entity.
IntelliJ Data view will call entity's `toString()` method and proxy entity will ask database to get real entity.

Disable toString object view in IntelliJ preference

[image]